# ssh remote command ls hangs when using '*'

Tags: linux, ssh, oracle-linux

i'm having a problem with remote command in ssh.

The following commands run just fine:

```
ssh remote_server ls /path/to/folder/
```

(list all files of the folder - OK)

```
ssh remote_server ls /path/to/folder/file_000*
```

(wildcard match one file of the folder - OK)

The following command hangs:

```
ssh remote_server ls /path/to/folder/file*
```

(wildcard matchs some of the files - HANGS)

```
ssh remote_server ls /path/to/folder/*
```

(wildcard matchs all the files - HANGS)

The remote folder does not have a unreasonable amount of files: about 50, 40 of them would match 'file*' regex.

Running ssh with -vvv flag gives me the following output

```
[...]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 136 bytes for a total of 2469
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env ORACLE_SID
debug3: Ignored env ORACLE_BASE
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env CLASSPATH
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env ORACLE_HOME
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: ls /u01/app/oracle/backup/rman/*
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 152 bytes for a total of 2621
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

in which point, hangs.

Any ideas?

Source is Oracle Linux 6.9
Destiny is Oracle Linux 7.5

Comment: What you get when you do: ssh -T remote_server ls /path/to/folder/ ssh -T: Disable pseudo-terminal allocation. This prevents the server aborting the transaction entirely if a text-terminal (tty) is requested.

Comment: Same behavior =S

Answer (score 2):

The bash wildcard expansion works this way that `/some/thing*` in your command is always expanded on your local system, even if there is `ssh` at the beginning of the line. Unexpected, but still.

To accomplish your intended task, always use quotes:  `ssh user@host 'ls /path/to/file*'`

In your successful test: if your system does not have `/path/to/folder/file_000*` it sends the same string `/path/to/folder/file_000*` to remote.

In your bad test: If your system has `/path/to/folder/file_some_name` and `/path/to/folder/file_yet_another` then it sends these strings to remote instead of `/path/to/folder/file*`

First of all the hang may be on the local system during listing local files - such as hang at the  filesystem level.

Secondly, as you send a textually much longer string through the network, you might hit the MTU problem (maximum transfer unit). The MTU problem goes unnoticed if all packets are smaller than the MTU.

### Suggested test case

To test for only network problem and only in one direction:

```
ssh user@host  'echo Type here some text that is longer than 1500 bytes > /tmp/delete_me'
```

Comment: hi kubanczyk, tks for your time. I forgot to add this information after i post the question, but the problem also happens with quotes.

But i agree with you about the MTU problem. There is a VPN between these 2 servers that is out of my administration.

Comment: This problem does not happens between each of these servers and others server in the same network of each of them.

Comment: hi  @kubanczyk, the test case works ok. tried a small text and a bigger text (bigger than 1500 bytes) and worked ok

Comment: on the other hand, ICMP if filtered by one of the hosts when package is bigger than 1422 bytes

Comment: i did another test. there is two files in remote host:
/tmp/delete with 1300 bytes
/tmp/delete2 with 1500 bytes

ssh user@host "cat /tmp/delete" OK
ssh user@host "cat /tmp/delete2" HANGS

Comment: So an MTU problem ingress. Network/VPN is responsible.